# indexing with iterators

Tags: c++

Is there a way that I can get the count number for an iterator?

so if at first I had this:

```
for (int i = 0; iter < agents.size(); ++i)
{
    agents[i]->Index(i);
}
```

bearing in mind that Index() sets an integer, how would I do this with iterators?

```
for (std::vector<Agent*>::iterator iter = agents.begin(); iter < agents.end(); ++iter)
{
    (*iter)->Index(????)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `distance` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/distance/

```
(*iter)->Index(distance(agents.begin(),iter));
```

Comment: I would be inclined to only use the difference of random access iterators or use a count! If the iterators din't support subtraction the effort in the loop becomes quadratic. Keeping a count has comparatively neglible costs.

Answer (score 2):

You **can** substract iterators:

```
int distance = iter - agents.begin();
```

EDIT:

Only works for random access iterators. (+1 internet to Let_Me_Be)

Comment: @Let_Me_Be I didn't know that. What's a random access iterators? Is the one in the question a random access iterator?

Comment: Yes it will work in this case, but it won't work universally. Of course the problem is that while this either works in constant time, or doesn't work, the distance will have linear complexity for cases when the iterators aren't random access iterators. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/RandomAccessIterator/

Comment: would it not be agents.begin() + iter? if not, why not?

Comment: The 'distance' between 5 and 7 is 7 - 5 = 2. In the same fashion, the distance between the iterator and the start of the vector is the iterator (7) minus the start (5).

Answer (score 1):

Most generally, you can always hack up something yourself:

```
{
    int i = 0;
    for (auto it = agents.begin(), end = agents.end(); it != end; ++it, ++i)
    {
         (*it)->set_int(i);
    }
}
```

If you have random access iterators, you can indeed use `std::distance(agents.begin(), it)` safely, as has been said already.

Comment: If you have random access iterators, you don't need `std::distance`, you could just subtract. `std::distance` will work for any read class of iterator.